# Simple implementation of 2D rectangle packing in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, knapsack-problem, packing

I have been searching for a 2D-packing algorithm that I can use for my program:

**Imagine I have a big wooden plate and smaller plates to cut from this big plate. I know the size of the big plate and sizes (and number) of the smaller plates. I have to write an algorithm to best fit the small plates in the big plate, so there would be as little waste as possible. The rectangles are also allowed to rotate.**

Now, please don't point me to the literature as I have been studying it since yesterday, bin-packing, 2d-knapsack problem, I came across all of those suggestions and I understand what I am looking for, what I can't do is write a simple code example out of it, as all of the examples I have found are VERY, VERY complex and what I need is **a fairly simple solution** (which will probably cost me effectiveness of fitting, which is fine).

Can somebody please write a short example for me? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Are the rectangles allowed to rotate 90 degrees?

Comment: You could have a look at: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu

Comment: Yeah, I know of this page. There are so many classes there that I get lost, I need some basic example to start with basic logic so I can work on it, not start with difficult ones.

Comment: @Aldert does this work for fixed dimension rectangle?